# Using PHP and cURL to login to indyarocks.com

Tags: php, libcurl

I am new to cURL and don't know much about it. I basically want to login to my account on www.indyarocks.com through libcurl for PHP. I don't know what type of authentication it uses (I don't know how to find that out.). When I go to http://www.indyarocks.com, I get a login form which asks for my username and password. I put in my username and password and click login and everything is good. I tried to automate this using cURL. This is a snippet of my code.

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.indyarocks.com/loginchk.php");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
```

I looked at the source of the login page and found out the address of the page to which the username and password are sent (the action attribute of the form) which is "http://www.indyarocks.com/loginchk.php" and set it as the target url. When I run this, I get username or password is wrong error and the login fails. My username and password is correct. I don't know what the problem is. Can the password be encrypted? Can that be responsible for this failure?
Please help me get around this problem. I'll be really thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just guessing... it is likely that you have to send POST variables. Alternatively you can just send a cookie with no need to login. There are various FF extensions that let you explore cookies. Personally I would suggest the "Web Developer" extension, that does much more than that.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use HTTP authentication, but the site uses something else. You need to replicate the user posting the form. Check the form fields' names, and post them. You'll need `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=" .$username.'&password='.$password);
```

also include any hidden fields in the form, there probably is!.
anyways in the future you could use a local proxy to determine what exactly is sent to the server, try using [burp suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) or [tamper data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/)

Comment: can you explain more what the proxy is for. Is this something that gets done once when you're writing the code or with every request. +1 from me for the links.

Comment: @sami a proxy is like an intermediate server between the client computer and the web server http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server for more information, a local proxy is a proxy server that is hosted on the client computer and used to intercept the requests that are being made from your browser to the server. It is mostly used in web application testing.